# How do I split a Text with 3 delimiters in SQL (Oracle) into multiple rows and columns?

Tags: sql, split, delimiter

I need to split a text like **"Aa:One|Bb:Two,Three,Four|Cc:Five,Six"** into rows and columns for the result to look like -

**Col1    Col2**

AA       One

Bb       Two

Bb       Three

Bb       Four

Cc       Five

Cc       Six

I have tried using

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^:]+', 1, 1)    AS COL1
      ,REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^:]+', 1, 2)    AS COL2
FROM (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Aa:One|Bb:Two,Three,Four|Cc:Five,Six', '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) AS str
      FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY INSTR('Aa:One|Bb:Two,Three,Four|Cc:Five,Six', '|', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
      )
```

But I could only create

**Col1    Col2**

Aa   One

Bb   Two,Three,Four

Cc Five,Six

I am not sure how to split it further with  **comma(,)** in Col2 into rows against the Col1 value's first occurrence

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the temp table logic 'WITH t AS ()' to create the result set with the below query -

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^:]+', 1, 1))    AS tempCol1
  ,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^:]+', 1, 2))    AS tempCol2
FROM (
  SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Aa:One|Bb:Two,Three,Four|Cc:Five,Six|Dd:Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten', '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY INSTR('Aa:One|Bb:Two,Three,Four|Cc:Five,Six|Dd:Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten', '|', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0)
)

SELECT DISTINCT(Col1)
   , Col2
FROM (
   SELECT t.tempCol1 AS Col1
     ,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.tempCol2, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) Col2
   FROM t
   CONNECT BY INSTR(t.tempCol2, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0)
ORDER BY Col1, Col2
```

Apparently, I had to use 'Distinct' for Col1 as the query would fetch duplicate rows.

Thanks all for the help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for `SQL Server`. You can get the same result from `ORACLE` using the alternates for the `Functions` in `ORACLE`.

```
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(100)='Aa:One|Bb:Two,Three,Four|Cc:Five,Six'

SELECT LEFT(items, CHARINDEX(':',items)-1)Col1
    ,RIGHT(items, CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(items))-1)Col2 
INTO #Temp
FROM dbo.Split(@Id,'|')

SELECT p.Col1, colortable.items as Col2
FROM #Temp p 
    cross apply split(p.Col2, ',') as colortable

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

And my Result is:

```
Col1    Col2
Aa      One
Bb      Two
Bb      Three
Bb      Four
Cc      Five
Cc      Six
```

Comment: Your logic helped me get the desired result. Thanks a lot ! :)